# Laravel set recursive function to get parent and its child

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I am creating a roles management module in my system. I am fetching the module permission in config file. Array look like :

```
"user_management" => array:3 [▼
"display_name" => "Users"
"permissions" => []
"child" => array:2 [▼
  "user_internal_management" => array:3 [▼
    "display_name" => "Roam Users"
    "permissions" => array:5 [▼
      "browse_user_internal" => "Browse Roam  Users"
      "view_user_internal" => "View Roam Users"
      "add_user_internal" => "Add Roam User"
      "edit_user_internal" => "Edit Roam User"
      "delete_user_internal" => "Delete Roam User"
    ]
    "child" => []
  ]
  "user_corporate_management" => array:3 [▼
    "display_name" => "Client Users"
    "permissions" => array:5 [▼
      "browse_user_corporate" => "Browse Client Users"
      "view_user_corporate" => "View Client Users"
      "add_user_corporate" => "Add Client User"
      "edit_user_corporate" => "Edit Client User"
      "delete_user_corporate" => "Delete Client User"
    ]
    "child" => []
  ]
]
]
```

Here `user_management` is parent and `user_internal_management & user_corporate_management` are child of `user_management`
What i want when i create a new role, I want to show only a particular permissions which logged in user has on add form.

So for that on create function I got all ID's which is permission of logged in users and ids of `permission` table.
I want to arrange this ID's array, which is define as above.
`parent> child > child`

I got permissions ID's array like ;

```
array:8 [▼
 0 => 1
 1 => 68
 2 => 69
 3 => 70
 4 => 71
 5 => 72
 6 => 73
 7 => 74
]
```

And my table look like[image]

How can i do this.?

Comment: most probably it is better to fetch data from db as flat and re-arrange in php to produce hierarchical structure or parent/child dependencies

Comment: @NikosM. thanx for quick response. I have tried another way that I got arranged array in `config/permissions` file which I set. What i face is i  want to remove all id's array which is not in `permissions ID's array` define as above.Any idea ?